# QGIS: Load GPX polygon (as polyline) creates additional lines (GPS Tools)

Tags: qgis, gpx, garmin, gpstools

this is slightly confusing: I want to upload a polygon to my Garmin Etrex Vista HCx in QGIS 3.10.3 using GPS Tools.

I have now managed
- to convert my polygon to GPX (convert to polyline, save as GPX, specs: CRS = EPGS:4326 – WGS84, FORCE GPX TRACK = YES, unselect all attributes)
- to upload the GPX track to my Garmin device using GPS tools.

The GPX track that is exported from my polyline looks just fine and matches my polygon boundaries. However, when I load the GPS using GPS tools so that I can upload it to my Garmin (without that step it doesn´t show up in the list for upload), I get a CONTINUOUS polyline, all points are somehow connected to each other, resulting in this picture (yellow being my polygon and red the resulting track): 
[image]

How can I avoid this behaviour?